# Wordpress plugins and {} in posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to update a plugin that used to work on an old version of wordpress however now doesn't want to. The plugin include's itself when {wpdir} (its a link directory like script) is inserted into a page, however right now all I can get is just the {wpdir} printed out.. I was wondering if there was some change in WP core lately and that doesn't work anymore?

IF so does anyone know how it was defined and what I should change it to?

Comment: WPDir PRO it's a paid plugin I believe

Comment: Are you sure? Shortcodes in WP are written as [wpdir], for example. The plugin may, of course, take a prepared page code and parse it for {wpdir} by itself.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Does your server meet all of the requirements? http://www.wpdirectorypro.com/requirements.php